# Finding an efficient estimator for a distribution

Tags: statistics

Let $f_Y(y,\lambda)=\frac{y}{\lambda^2}e^{-y/\lambda}$ where $0 \leq y$ and $\lambda\geq0$.  The Cramer-Rao bound to this is $\theta^2/4n$.  However, for $Y$, we have $E(Y)=\lambda$ and $\operatorname{Var}(Y)=2\lambda^2$.  Hence $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{n}\sum Y_i$ is not an efficient estimator.

I understand how to demonstrate something is not efficient, but how does one go about finding the efficient estimator.

Comment: I think the expectation is wrong: $Y$ is Distributed as $Y\sim \Gamma (2,\lambda)$. So $E[Y]=2\lambda$ and $Var[Y] = 2\lambda^2$. Both the MLE and moment-estimator are $\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{2} \overline{Y}$. You don't say what $\theta$ is in your question.

Comment: Is the thing you're calling $\theta$ the same thing as what you're calling $\lambda$?  If so, I think you should use the same letter both times.

Comment: The thing you're calling $n$ would conventionally be the sample size, with an i.i.d. sample.  It might not be a bad thing to mention such a sample in the way you phrase the question.

Comment: If we assume hypotheses mentioned by @MichaelHardy and $\theta=\lambda$ then your Cramer-Rao inequality is wrong. It should be $C.R. = (I(\lambda))^{-1} = \frac{\lambda^2}{2n}$.

Comment: Rao--Blackwell can improve crude estimators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume the sample $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. and that $\theta =\lambda$ in your question then your Cramer-Rao inequality is wrong. It should be
$$\text{C.R.} = (I(\lambda))^{-1} = \frac{\lambda^2}{2n}.$$

In such a case $\hat{\lambda} = \frac{1}{2} \overline{Y}$ is indeed an efficient estimator (and unbiased since it is a moment-estimator)

Yes, because:
$$\operatorname{Var}[\hat{\lambda}] = \operatorname{Var}\left[ \frac{1}{2n}\sum_i Y_i\right] = \frac{1}{4n^2} \sum_i \operatorname{Var}[Y_i] = \frac{1}{4n} \operatorname{Var}[Y_1] = \frac{1}{4n} 2\lambda^2 = \frac{\lambda^2}{2n} = \text{C.R.}$$